# SwiftUI Canvas won't build with modulization

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Recently I started working on a project that is modularized and the project builds fine for the simulator and device, but the canvas fails with the errors below.

- `no such file or directory: '/Users/profileName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
- `LinkDylibError: Failed to build SurveyResultsView.swift`
- `Linking failed: no such file or directory:`
- `clang: error: no such file or directory: '`
- `BuildInvocationError`

I tried updating the `Framework Search Paths` to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../path/to/my/framework`

Comment: You have to add the framework to the test modules

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit new to modulization, in the package or in the main app? For my educational purposes, how did you determine that from above?

Comment: Likely the app, impossible to tell with the info you have provided. Canvas uses the Test targets.

Comment: I added some screenshots above, if that helps.

Comment: No, considering you haven't even said which framework includes `SurveyResultsView` and we have no other info about the framework and your setup. My suggestion might not even be the right thing, you want us to help you with out eyes closed, you likely just have to research and troubleshoot, there are a lot of question out there about this.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not trying to get help with eyes closed. I'm not sure what to provide to help assist.